# Получение значения из Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Не могу получить значение из Intent. Когда смотрю на содержимое интента в отладчике (на то что возвращает getIntent()), то вижу следующее:

```
4 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830031883632} "name" -> " ЛН Хлопья ржаные 0,4 (25)"
3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830031883376} "koef" -> "25"
2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830031883224} "nomPice" -> "3"
1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830031883064} "price" -> "11.7"
0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830031882904} "position" -> "0"
```

Мне необходимо вытянуть значение с ключом "position", как видно из отладчика интент его содержит. Делаю вот что:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(BasicSettings.NOM_NAME,getIntent().getStringExtra(BasicSettings.NOM_NAME));
intent.putExtra(BasicSettings.NOM_PRICE,getIntent().getStringExtra(BasicSettings.NOM_PRICE));
intent.putExtra(BasicSettings.NOM_KOEFF,getIntent().getStringExtra(BasicSettings.NOM_KOEFF));
intent.putExtra(BasicSettings.CURRENT_POSITION,getIntent().getStringExtra(BasicSettings.CURRENT_POSITION));
intent.putExtra(BasicSettings.NOM_PIECE,Integer.parseInt(productPieceEditText.getText().toString()));
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

Формирую новый интент из тех значений что были переданы в активность при её открытии. И если все остальные значение ложатся в новый интент как нужно,то значение с ключом "position" не достается.
Вот что происходит:
`getIntent()` - возвращает интент со значением по ключу "position", т.е. с ним все норм.
а вот этот кусочек кода возвращает null:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra(BasicSettings.CURRENT_POSITION);
```

Константы из класса BassicSettings:

```
public static final String NOM_NAME = "name";
public static final String NOM_KOEFF= "koef";
public static final String NOM_PRICE = "price";
public static final String CURRENT_POSITION = "position";
public static final String NOM_PIECE = "nomPice";
```

В какую сторону вести поиск решения?

Comment: Покажите код создания интента, откуда потом достаете данные.

Comment: Разобрался, смутили кавычки в отладчике, само значение целочисленное, его нужно было доставать getIntExtra(), вместо getStringExtra().